# Diccionarios y codificacion

Tags: python-3.x

Elaboro un diccionario
diccionario = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c", 4:"d", 5:"e", 6:"f", 7:"g", 8:"h", 9:"i", ...}
 y quiero que al meter un mensaje el programa de devuelva la misma frase con las claves a las que pertenece cada caracter.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Lo más eficiente será que hagas un diccionario inverso. Asumiendo que los valores en tu `diccionario` no se repiten, puedes crear el inverso fácilmente así:

```
dict_inverso = { letra: codigo for codigo, letra in diccionario.items() }
```

Después lo tienes tan fácil como:

```
letra = "f"
codigo = dict_inverso[letra]
```

**Nota**. Si realmente el código de cada letra es como has escrito, comenzando en 1 y correlativamente por orden alfabético, entonces no necesitas diccionario alguno (ni siquiera el que ya tienes). Puedes obtener el código de una letra con la expresión `ord(letra) - ord('a') + 1` y a la inversa, dado el código, puedes obtener la letra correspondiente con `chr(codigo + ord('a') - 1)`